# using bcc function gives error :Address in mailbox given [$users] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: laravel, bcc

i have to send the bulk emails using bcc but it gives error,i also read somewhere bcc function takes 2 parameters but this also didn't work.var_dump($users) it giving correct output

```
 public function welcomeEmails()
{ 
        $users = User::select('email')->whereIn('id',[5,6,7]->get()->toArray();  
         Mail::send('emails.welcome_email', [], function($message) use ($users)
         {     
            $message->to(abc@gmail.com)
                    ->bcc('$users')
                    ->subject('Welcome to the jobsee');     
         }); 
            Session::flash('success', 'Your message was sent!'); 
            return redirect()->back();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably due to an invalid email address. This error is usually returned by the server and has nothing to do with Laravel.

Comment: i also tried with valid email address but nothing seems fine,error is same